# command-delete key remapping

Tags: macos, keyboard, ukelele

I have remapped one of my top-left keys (<kbd>`</kbd>) to the backward-delete key (<kbd>⌫</kbd>). However the command-delete shortcut (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd>) to "move to trash" works only on the original <kbd>⌫</kbd> key but not on the remapped key. Any suggestion?

I have remapped the key using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele). I entered `"&#x0008";` as the identifier for <kbd>⌫</kbd>.

[fyi: purpose is to symmetrize and reduce wrist pain; likewise I remapped caps-lock to enter/return; I'm a customized Dvorak keyboard user; first experience on a Mac]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) instead. Save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, KeyCode::DELETE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and tick the checkbox for the setting.

Comment: Thanks Lauri, I won't have time to try this for a couple of days as my laptop is getting an upgrade, but will try asap.